# Size limit to number of items in a struct

Tags: solidity, struct, gas-limit

If I loop over mapping into a struct the gas fee is very low. However, in trying to test its limits, the EVM often causes Remix to crash in creating edge cases, because I'm creating blocks of 50 new structs. It does not crash on the loop where I read data and do some algebra, however, and in practice new structs would be added one at a time.

For example, I find that I can basically get to a loop that runs through 7000 items if I extrapolate from a mapping with 200 structs. However, given Remix is often crashing, and it takes a long time to run this loop (seemingly more than proportional to the gas), I wonder if in practice I should lower my estimate of the maximum set of struct members some percentage.

The basic idea looks something like this:

```
mapping(bytes32 => Contract) public contracts;
bytes32[] public customerContracts;
uint public totalBalance

struct Contract {
    address customer;
    uint inventory;
}

function totalInventory()
public
{
 uint temporaryBalance;
 for (uint i = 0; i < contracts.length; i++) {
     Subcontract storage k = contracts[customerContracts[i]];
     temporaryBalance += k.inventory;
 }
 totalBalance = temporaryBalance;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remix IDE is not authoritative. If it crashes, it's a failure of the simulation. In the end, the network block gasLimit is a hard stop. That value is voted on by miners and has been known to drop during periods of high congestion. Caution about cutting it too close.

I think you should have a look over here. https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad

Another thing that jumps out is the storage i/o cost. It all looks like a classic approach without much regard to the paradigm changes in Ethereum. You need to economize on storage and transaction complexity and be mindful of gas costs.

Instead of iterating over the structure, consider tallying that total as you go. This has desirable effects:

1. The cost of updating it is borne by the users who are updating something.
2. The work is amortized. That is, each transaction does a little work to keep the value current. That will be O(1) so the gas cost per transaction will be scale-invariant (the same in any case).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, loops are bad, but I was more curious about whether accessing such a struct using the extreme example of a loop reading from n items, was O(n^2).

Comment: No, it doesn't compound. The mapping helps zero in on a "slot" in storage known by a unique key. More than likely, just Remix jamming up. I get that as well on monster contracts. It doesn't mean the contract is broken. It's stability in the browser, etc.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments! Reading your 'Getting Loopy' post, you recommend to not 'Search for a record of interest in a list of unlimited size.' Yet, if I am not looping, it seems my struct can accumulate an unlimited size without hurting efficiency. That is, if all my interactions are piecemeal, say pulling the struct data for customer 73, it doesn't matter if my struct has 100 or 1e5 customers other customers.

Comment: That's the whole idea. You make it so the size of the dataset is irrelevant. In fact, that is what you _must do_ in smart contracts.

Comment: So then, it what way is it bad to 'search for a record of interest in a list of unlimited size'? Only if your are looping or doing something similar?

Comment: "Searching" is bad. "Going" is good. Using a hash table means you find everything in one operation - O(1). Not like a binary search O(log n) or a sequential search O(n). You need to develop an intuition for avoiding any process that increases as a factor of `n` because it won't scale.

Comment: In case it is not clear, mappings use hash tables. So if you know the key you need from a mapping, or the row you need in an array, you're good. If you have to `for(i=0; i<range ...` you are probably getting into trouble. An exception to that heuristic is when `range` is known to be limited by some other factor so you can show there is a maximum cost for that step in any scenario.

Comment: I think I know what you mean: Operations that process a single instance of `contracts[customerContracts[i]]' are fine no matter how many customerContracts are in contracts.  But just a thought on semantics: 'searching' in my intuition seems more akin to a finding a struct given a key from a mapping, good coding, while 'going' seems more like a looping-type algorithm. Eg, looping often 'goes' on and on, while using a hash table seems more like a search. Perhaps that's because I'm not a hard core programmer.

Comment: The platform challenges long-held assumptions about how computers and databases work, and intuitive ideas of time, performance and cost. I try to use different words until the concept is clear. Sorry if I seemed to mislead you.

Comment: Deep down, there is a "storage layout" with a scheme for finding the elements of a struct in the mapping - by mapping index and element. A 32-byte "slot" is computed and then its lookup is accomplished in "one move" at a fixed gas cost. The client-side database implementation of the protocol, including the organization of the key/value pairs, is mostly irrelevant. The operation is a fixed cost (gas) and Ethereum protocol is silent on implementation details. It doesn't matter than the client might need to fish around in an index to find it.